# fixing unexpected curly brackets in R

Tags: r

I've written the following code:

```
extract_distract <- function(dataset, type="increase"){
  if(dataset = wfh){
    if(type = "decrease"){
      decr_distract <- str_subset(decr_product, "distract")
      str_extract(decr_distract, ".{0,30}distract+.{0,30}")
    } else if(type = "increase"){
      incr_distract <- str_subset(incr_product, "distract")
      str_extract(incr_distract, ".{0,30}distract+.{0,30}")
      } else{stop("NA - use either increase or decrease type")}
    } else{stop("NA - use (dataset = wfh)")}}
```

Everytime i try to run it it gives me the following error:

```
>       } else{stop("NA - use either increase or decrease type")}
Error: unexpected '}' in "      }"
>     } else{stop("NA - use (dataset = wfh)")}}
Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"
```

I am new to this but would appreciate any help

Comment: It's very confusing that this problem caused this error, but I believe the issue is that `if(dataset = wfh)` should be `if(dataset == wfh)`.

Comment: There are a few problems here. The most important is that you are using `=` to test equality, which will produce an error. You should use `==`. Also, don't get a single logical result by testing the equality of dataframes - you get a vectorized result. Try `if(identical(dataset, wfh))`. Furthermore, a function shouldn't rely on the presence or name of variables in the global environment. You should pass in `incr_product` and `desc_product` as arguments to the function.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you, changed it to 'dataset ==' and 'type ==' then it worked - rookie mistake :)

Comment: And I'd add `wfh` to Allan's list variables used in the function that should also be passed in... unless you are trying to check the name of the dataset passed in, in which case `deparse(substitute(dataset)) == "wfh"` might be what you're looking for...

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a good idea to pay most attention to the first error, not the last ones.  If I run your code, I see

```
> extract_distract <- function(dataset, type="increase"){
+   if(dataset = wfh){
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"extract_distract <- function(dataset, type="increase"){
  if(dataset ="
>     if(type = "decrease"){
Error: unexpected '=' in "    if(type ="
>       decr_distract <- str_subset(decr_product, "distract")
Error in str_subset(decr_product, "distract") : 
  could not find function "str_subset"
>       str_extract(decr_distract, ".{0,30}distract+.{0,30}")
Error in str_extract(decr_distract, ".{0,30}distract+.{0,30}") : 
  could not find function "str_extract"
>     } else if(type = "increase"){
Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"
>       incr_distract <- str_subset(incr_product, "distract")
Error in str_subset(incr_product, "distract") : 
  could not find function "str_subset"
>       str_extract(incr_distract, ".{0,30}distract+.{0,30}")
Error in str_extract(incr_distract, ".{0,30}distract+.{0,30}") : 
  could not find function "str_extract"
>       } else{stop("NA - use either increase or decrease type")}
Error: unexpected '}' in "      }"
>     } else{stop("NA - use (dataset = wfh)")}}
Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"
```

The first error is `Error: unexpected '=' in: ...`, which would have led you to the solution mentioned by @GregorThomas:  you should have used `==`, not `=`.  The reason this caused all the other errors is that R discards the incorrect lines.  After they are gone, the rest of your code doesn't make sense.